Solana SPL-Token and "Segmentation fault"
Dear Community members
After spending hours online in finding the root cause of segmentation fault, I am finally posting this thread, while hoping to obtain a support.
As a matter of fact, running these commands (a priori, simple) still produce error:
spl-token create-token

Result: Segmentation fault
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-metadata

Result: Segmentation fault
From a Youtube tutorial
spl-token create-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb

Result: Segmentation fault
solana config get
===================================================

Config File: /root/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com 
WebSocket URL: wss://api.devnet.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /root/.config/solana/demo.json 
Commitment: confirmed

spl-token --version
spl-token-cli 4.0.0
solana --version
solana-cli 2.0.3

Is it due to the fact that my wsl uses by default root@ leading to permission issues? In that case I've used chmod targeting /root/.config/solana/demo.json.
Many thanks in advance for your assistance, as I am running out of ideas.
Merry Christmas!
